# Creating a Linux Userlist with Python

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am writing a script in Python that will look at all of the groups AND all of the users on a linux system, and output me a file.

I have a situation where if an account is in a certain group, I want to set the user ID myself (in this example, it is because the account/s is a Non User Account)

Code below:

```
#/usr/bin/python
import grp,pwd,os
from os.path import expanduser


destdir = expanduser("~")
destfile = '/newfile.txt'
appname = 'app name'
groupid = ''
userid = ''

#delete old feed file and create file
if os.path.exists(destdir + destfile):
        os.remove(destdir + destfile)
        print "file deleted...creating new file"
        output = open(destdir + destfile, 'w+')
        output.write('ACCOUNTID|USERLINKID|APPLICATIONROLE|APPLICATION' + '\n')
else:
        print "no file to delete...creating file"
        output = open(destdir + destfile, 'w+')
        output.write('ACCOUNTID|USERLINKID|APPLICATIONROLE|APPLICATION' + '\n')


#get user/group data for all users non primary groups
#documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html
groups = grp.getgrall()
for group in groups:
    groupid = group[2]
    print groupid #checking to see if group ids print correctly. Yes it does
    for user in group[3]:
        if groupid == '33': #Issue is here!
                userid = 'qwerty'
                print userid #testing var
                output.write(user + '|' + userid + '|' + group[0] + '|' + appname + '\n')
```

The issue is here:

```
if groupid == '33': #Issue is here!
                userid = 'qwerty'
                print userid #testing var
```

The variable "userid" is never set to it's value and never prints anything while testing.

The group "33" does have users in it and exists. I cannot figure out why this doesn't work :(

I have another piece of code that does this for users (as I am looking at both Primary and Secondary groups, and once I figure out this part, I can fix the rest)

Answer (score 0):

Your validate of groupid is against a string, it is an integer

```
if groupid == 31: # then do something
```